# Suppress 'Use' command output while running MSSQL Server script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I have a basic sql script that I am executing via sqlcmd.  The first line in the output is the Use command to specify the database.  I'm writing the results out to a text file, but don't want to include the response from the 'use' command, just the query.  In other words, I don't want to see "Changed database context to 'database_name'." at the top of the output.  Is there a way to suppress this output?

Comment: Thanks JiggsJedi for the quick response!  Have to make sure you include the '.dbo' in the full database/table name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
USE someDB
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeTable
```

You could try:

```
SELECT * FROM someDB.dbo.SomeTable
```

Comment: Nice!  I tried that earlier but failed to include '.dbo'